# Using File.Exists to check if a file name exists - always returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net, verify

File Name exists and ASP.NET C# is always returning false.

I have been trying File.Exists

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.MapPath("~");
        string location = ("~/Uploads/");
        string filename = TextBox1.Text;
        string currentfile = (location + filename);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(currentfile))
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "File Exists in Uploads";
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "File Name Not Found";
        }
    }
```

''''

I hope to see an output that checks with TextBox1 user input if the filename entered exists in the Uploads folder

Comment: Look into `Server.MapPath`

Answer (score 0):

in your if statement instead of passing the relative path have it locate the path using server.mapth path

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(currentfile))){

}
```

try this it should work without a problem